# in a CodenameOne UI Designer App, why might Android scroll but iOS truncates?

Tags: codenameone

I have a BorderLayout Form where the Center is a ScollableY container which is BorderLayout with it's center having a container where I add items dynamically (BoxLayoutY).

The problem I'm having is that on Android Simulator and Device, it scrolls as it should but on iOS Simulator it truncates the dynamic list of items when its out of room.

What should I be checking in my UI Designer or Dynamic Loading Code to determine what could be causing this strange inconsistency?

I've attached a screenshot of both side by side.
[image: iOS Truncates instead of Scrolling]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a `BorderLayout` `Container` scrollable. We implicitly disable this to prevent a common mistake. It looks like what you really want to do is to make the `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` scrollable on Y.

Comment: Thanks Shai, I can see what you mean now.  the BorderLayout is made to lay out a screen but since I need a layout that can grow and shrink, it doesn't make as much sense anymore.  BoxLayoutY worked perfectly.